# Document.write on a different html page

Tags: javascript, html

Hmm is it possible to `document.write` on other html page?

For example I create a two html page, the first page have a textfield and submit button. I enter a text in a textfield and after I click the submit button the value of the textfield will be transfer to the second html page and load the html page and write the value on it.

Just a beginner to javascript so bear with me please :D

Comment: No. But you could use `localStorage` to sync value between to sites.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Not in pure javascript, it isn't (well, it is, technically, but it would mean you would have to have both pages up on the same browser, just different tabs). Javascript is local to the browser, and can't save anything except with localStorage - what you can do is run an AJAX-call, update something in the background, and have the other page check for updates.

Comment: Another possibility would be to load page2.html?value=textFromTextbox after the user clicked the submit button on page1, and extract the value from the url on the second page

Comment: The pattern you are describing is typically implemented without javascript using an [HTML Form Post](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp).

Comment: I wasn't sure whether OP was familiar with this, so I tried to give a high-level overview over the procedure.
Nitpicking: it would need to be a form using the GET method and not a POST if no server side code is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using pure javascript and HTML, I assume server-side things are out of the picture. So Felix Kling's comment is actually, I think, a good way to go. Here's one way you could use `localStorage` to make this work:

```
/* index.html */
<form action="result.html" onsubmit="submit()">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
function submit() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  localStorage.input = input;
}
</script>

/* result.html */
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.input;
</script>
```

Comment: can i store multiple value like 'var x = 1; var y = 2; localStorage.input = x; localStorage.input = y' ?

Comment: `localStorage` is an object, so you can say something like `localStorage.x = 1;` and `localStorage.y = 2;`. It's just an object that gets saved so you can read it again later, even on a different page or after a refresh. However, it isn't reliable as long-term storage. Look into WebSQL for long-term storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Query String.

```
window.location = "Pass.aspx?variabletopass=test";
```

Use this line of where you are trying to redirect your page,and value of your textfield in query string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Single page Application you can quite easily achieve this, by just storing the value in correct scope. 
If you are on multiple page application you can achieve this by any of the following ways:

1. sending parameter in url
2. storing value in localStorage/sessionStorage
3. storing it in cookie(Not recommended)
4. sending it to server in forms param(Not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Without using php you can document.write() submitted text on other html file as follows.

```
  <html>
   <script>
   var a =  document.location.toString();
  var b = a.slice(a.indexOf("?")+1,a.length);
  var c = b.split("&");
  for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){
 document.write(c[i]);
  }
 </script>
 </html>
```